# await doesn't seem to stop the function

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I'm not sure what it is.

I have a corutine in my code that triggers when an user sends a message. Then the bot picks a random int, and based on the outcome it'll run a different function.

```
if rand == 1:  
                             
       UserWhoClicked = await gametasks.task1(message)
        
       print(UserWhoClicked)

       UserWhoClickedID = UserWhoClicked.id
```

UserWhoClicked is a variable where I need to store the Member object from the task1 function. My issue it that the corutine does not wait for task1 to be completed, and actually return what I need, but just keeps going. So an error is given saying that UserWhoClicked has no attribute .id because UserWhoClicked is None.

This is the task1 coroutine:

```
async def task1(message):
       
    
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="**CRITICAL ISSUE IN THE MAIN FRAME**", description="THE MAIN FRAME HAS FAILED AND REQUIRES INSTANT REPAIR", color=0xFF0000) #Embed
    button = discord.ui.Button(label = "Fix ",style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji = "")
       
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(button)
    message = await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar, view=view)

    async def button_callback(interaction): #When the button is pressed
           print(str(interaction.user.id) + " " + str(interaction.user) + " Ha premuto il pulsante")
           embedVar = discord.Embed(title="**CRITICAL ISSUE FIXED**", description="THE MAIN FRAME HAS BEEN FIXED", color=0x00FF00) #embed edit
            
           button = discord.ui.Button(label = "Fix ",style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, emoji = "",disabled=True)
            
           view.add_item(button)
           await message.edit(embed=embedVar,view=view)
           
           print(interaction.user)
           
           return(interaction.user)
           

    button.callback = button_callback       
    view.remove_item(button)
```

Everything works until I define button_callback. Then the last 2 lines are executed and the first coroutine just keeps going, fetching me an error.

the button_callback is waiting for an user to click a button on discord.

So, what do I need to do in order to make the first coroutine wait until task1 actually returns something?

For clarification, I want task1 to end only when the the coroutine button_callback is executed, since the return statement is in there. I do not want task1 to finish before that.

Comment: There is no `return` statement in `task1()` so python just puts `return None` at the end automatically.

Comment: the return statement is inside button_callback, and I don't want task1 to finish until button_callback is executed, since the return is in there.

Comment: That return statement is for the button callback as you said. Not task1.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: At the end of the documentation of the ["Future"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#future-object) object there is an example how to use a future in a callback situation. Basically create the future at beginning of "task1", set result of it near the end of "button_callback" and await it near the end of "task1".